# Android. GridLayoutManager

Tags: android, recyclerview, gridlayoutmanager

Есть GridLayoutManager и я хочу по клику на какой нибудь item прятать все, кроме горизонтальной линии, в которой находится item. Примерно выглядеть должно так.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть какие нибудь идеи, как это можно сделать?

Comment: можно в адаптер передавать, на какой итем был клик, и вызывать у него `notifyDataSetChanged()`,  и при перерисовке проверять, если итем находится в нужном ряду, то рисовать его ,как обычно, а если нет - просто прозрачным.

Comment: @metalurgus а как это правильно реализовать, я вообще не могу представить как это должно работать в коде.

Comment: что именно? Что конкретно не знаете, как реализовать? Как узнать, на какой строке был клик? Как передать в адаптер номер сроки? Как узнать номер строки текущего создаваемого элемента списка? Как сделать элемент списка прозрачным? Конкретнее опишите проблему, полный готовый код вам тут никто не предоставит.

Comment: @metalurgus как можно узнавать номер строки в котором был нажат item. И как скрыть все строки, кроме данной.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как можно узнавать номер строки в котором был нажат item

`GridLayoutManager` принимает в себя количество колонок. В зависимости от кол-ва колонок и позиции элемента, можно рассчитать, в какой строке он находится:

```
int row = position / columnCount;
```

> И как скрыть все строки, кроме данной.

В методе адаптера `onBindViewHolder()` рассчитать номер строки, в котором находится этот item.
Дальше сравнить его с номером строки кликнутого элемента, и если они не совпадают, то скрыть все `View` в данном item